# Cross product in underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, math, functional-programming, underscore.js

Is there a function built-in to underscore that would give the "cross product" of two arrays?

I have implemented a cross-product like this, but it would be nice if there were a built-in function for it --

```
domain = [];
_.each(x, function(x1) {
    _.each(y, function(y1) {
        domain.push([x1,y1]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the _cartesian_ product. The [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) is different.

Comment: You're right. The Cartesian product is the correct name for what I'm after.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [_.mixin](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin) to extend Underscore with your own function.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at _.mixin.